# space in reference after URL

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

[image]

In my 2nd and 3rd reference, there is a large space after URL, why and how can I remove it?

```latex
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{agsm} % Harvard style
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\end{document}
```

And the `ref.bib` entries with the problem.

```latex
@article{Tabish2007,
   author = {Syed Amin Tabish},
   issn = {1658-3639},
   issue = {2},
   journal = {International journal of health sciences},
   month = {7},
   pages = {V-VIII},
   pmid = {21475425},
   publisher = {Qassim University, Kingdom of Saudi Arabia},
   title = {Is Diabetes Becoming the Biggest Epidemic of the Twenty-first Century?},
   volume = {1},
   url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21475425 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3068646/},
   year = {2007},
}

@article{Ramachandran2014,
   author = {A Ramachandran},
   issn = {0971-5916},
   issue = {5},
   journal = {The Indian journal of medical research},
   keywords = {*Physical Examination,Diabetes Mellitus/diagnosis/*epidemiology/physiopathology,Humans,Prediabetic State/*diagnosis/epidemiology/physiopathology,Risk Factors},
   month = {11},
   pages = {579-581},
   pmid = {25579136},
   publisher = {Medknow Publications & Media Pvt Ltd},
   title = {Know the signs and symptoms of diabetes},
   volume = {140},
   url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25579136 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4311308/},
   year = {2014},
}
```

Comment: I guess the content of `ref.bib` might be helpful.

Comment: I have added the `ref.bib` entries.

Comment: What if right before the `\bibliography` you issue `\raggedright`? (The large space seems to be due to the paragraphs being justified.)

Comment: Note that it does not make any sense to provide two URLs in the `url` field. It is only meant for one. Additionally the `&` in the publisher needs to be `\&`

Comment: `\raggedright` works, but 2 urls is my problem, I downloaded it from the article website, did not notice there are 2 URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using something like this (after you pare down the `url` field in the `bib` file to contain only one url, and not two). The redefinition of `\harvardurl` enables proper URL breaking, the default does not, additionally the `xurl` package modifies `\url` such that it can break a URL at basically any char.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xurl}

\renewcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} {\itshape\urlstyle{same}\url{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Tabish2007,
   author = {Syed Amin Tabish},
   issn = {1658-3639},
   issue = {2},
   journal = {International journal of health sciences},
   month = {7},
   pages = {V-VIII},
   pmid = {21475425},
   publisher = {Qassim University, Kingdom of Saudi Arabia},
   title = {Is Diabetes Becoming the Biggest Epidemic of the Twenty-first Century?},
   volume = {1},
   url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21475425},
   year = {2007},
}

@article{Ramachandran2014,
   author = {A Ramachandran},
   issn = {0971-5916},
   issue = {5},
   journal = {The Indian journal of medical research},
   keywords = {*Physical Examination,Diabetes Mellitus/diagnosis/*epidemiology/physiopathology,Humans,Prediabetic State/*diagnosis/epidemiology/physiopathology,Risk Factors},
   month = {11},
   pages = {579-581},
   pmid = {25579136},
   publisher = {Medknow Publications \& Media Pvt Ltd},
   title = {Know the signs and symptoms of diabetes},
   volume = {140},
   url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25579136},
   year = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{agsm} % Harvard style
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `bibtex` doesn't like multiple URLs just separated by a whitespace. A quick fix that did work is to replace this space with a `~`. However, the line becomes very wide and does not respect margins. Also possible would be a linebreak just enforced by `\\`.

```
@article{Tabish2007,
   author = {Syed Amin Tabish},
   issn = {1658-3639},
   issue = {2},
   journal = {International journal of health sciences},
   month = {7},
   pages = {V-VIII},
   pmid = {21475425},
   publisher = {Qassim University, Kingdom of Saudi Arabia},
   title = {Is Diabetes Becoming the Biggest Epidemic of the Twenty-first Century?},
   volume = {1},
   url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21475425,\\https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3068646/},
   year = {2007},
}

@article{Ramachandran2014,
   author = {A Ramachandran},
   issn = {0971-5916},
   issue = {5},
   journal = {The Indian journal of medical research},
   keywords = {*Physical Examination,Diabetes Mellitus/diagnosis/*epidemiology/physiopathology,Humans,Prediabetic State/*diagnosis/epidemiology/physiopathology,Risk Factors},
   month = {11},
   pages = {579-581},
   pmid = {25579136},
   publisher = {Medknow Publications & Media Pvt Ltd},
   title = {Know the signs and symptoms of diabetes},
   volume = {140},
   url = {https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25579136,\\https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4311308/},
   year = {2014},
}
```